# Checkboxes inside dropdown menu does not work in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Nesting a checkboxes inside MenuItems inside a DropdownButton does not work; clicking the checkboxes has no effect:

```js
<Dropdown.Item>
         <Form.Check
               name={"title"}
               type="switch"
               defaultChecked={props?.searchIn?.title}
               onChange={props?.handleSearchIn} />
</Dropdown.Item>
```

If try to invoke outside from DropDownMenu its working.

Comment: could you add a code sandbox link to that behaviour?

Comment: Does putting the `<Form.Check>` outside of `<Dropdown.Item>` work for you?

Comment: @vatsalsoni https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxes-inside-dropdown-menu-does-not-work-in-react-hwi6pu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot for this problem, I found a simple solution. It can be useful for people who have this problem.

If you put any input directly in `Dropdown.Menu` without using `Dropdown.Item` , it works correctly.

```js
<Dropdown.Menu>
         <Form.Check
               name={"title"}
               type="switch"
               defaultChecked={props?.searchIn?.title}
               onChange={props?.handleSearchIn} />
</Dropdown.Menu>
```

Comment: Can you mark your answer as solved?

Comment: I can accept my own answer tomorrow